# How do you choose and implement SSL vs TLS protocal and their respective versions

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am very new to networking\security world. I am a application developer and usually don't need to worry about networking and Security aspect. Lately I am asked to connect to another server and I often come across SSL and TLS. I understand why we need these protocol and what are their benefits.

My question is at what point you choose one of these protocol? I believe, this is all driven by web server certificate. Is it right to say your web server certificate will drive the protocol selection & its version?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the certificate. The client and server negotiate the protocol between themselves, depending on what they each support and what they're each prepared to accept.

Comment: @Crowman: that was true for decades, but now there's a small exception: if your cert is an RSA key restricted by the algid to PSS then it can only be used with 1.3 _or_ 1.2 implementations that implement RFC8446 1.3 and 4.2.3 (which latter in practice will also implement, and prefer, and thus use, 1.3). But I don't know of any public CAs that are issuing RSA-PSS certs yet, so this would probably only happen in an enterprise/intranet situation.

Comment: @Crowman: When you setup client or server at what point of time you configure protocols ? I thought this was all driven by certificates

Comment: @OpenStack: At the beginning, clearly. Typically when you start a server, and when you configure a new client request, you specify a minimum TLS version, specify the cipher suites you're able and willing to accept, etc. Then during the handshake an attempt is made to agree upon a protocol which satisfies both sides. It's not driven by the certificates at all, except to the extent that the certificate(s) you have might limit the options you're able to accept (e.g. a server can't accept a cipher suite that uses RSA authentication if it doesn't possess an available certificate with an RSA key).

Comment: @Crowman: Is there anyway to check using what protocol client and server are configured on windows servers ?

Comment: @OpenStack: I don't really understand the question. If you want to check how software is configured, then you can just check the configuration. If you want to verify which protocol was actually negotiated for any given connection, you can log it, or use something like Wireshark to look at the packets. Either way, that's starting to get a bit off-topic for Stack Overflow.